# how to drag data (in uri format) from browser to other apps

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, electron

by using

```
dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", "application/octet-stream:fileName.bin:data:application/octet-stream;base64,eNcoDEdFiLEStuFf");
```

we can download file (written in uri format) to desktop (or any other folder).

but how to use uri format to drag into other apps.
e.g. drag pdf content in uri format from html page to adobe reader, so that it can render the content.

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUKJbXtrvsKMyAwIG9iago8PCAvTGVuZ3RoIDQgMCBSCiAgIC9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlCj4+CnN0cmVhbQp4nGWSQW4DIQxF95zCJ6BgwDDH6BGqkZIsJou295cKxjaMqkSZ/wX+9vPk2wUYn58nfHwFeP46qj4eB9Tm09HgDZhVX4DoKUf1GD0FhFp9Koc5glO0A8m6IKJvIW4++pzNx8B5 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
```

if it is possible, how to implement ?

```
dataTransfer.setData("application/pdf","content here ");
```

Answer (score 2):

To achive that:

You must be sure that client has the application you want to use. Many user use different application to open a pdf file.

The application that you want to use must registered itself to Operating System for incoming request. (For example on MacOS, App Store application registered itself and you can open an application page by clicking the html link)

if Adobe Reader is the application you want to use, you can search about if it has some future like this.

if you want to hide pdf files from search robots you can create them in your server temp folder and create a random link to them. After client use it, you can simply delete.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this answers the actual question (enabling drag & drop between applications).

Answer (score 2):

check out the Electron API documentation for [Dragging files out of a windows](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#dragging-files-out-of-the-window) (replicated here for archiving):

In web page:

```
<a href="#" id="drag">item</a>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  document.getElementById('drag').ondragstart = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    ipcRenderer.send('ondragstart', '/path/to/item')
  }
</script>
```

In the main process:

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('ondragstart', (event, filePath) => {
  event.sender.startDrag({
    file: filePath,
    icon: '/path/to/icon.png'
  })
})
```

Comment: already tried,  but it require path to actual file not the data (uri format)

Comment: How about writing the file to a temp folder instead of saving it to a variable?

Comment: writing temp file and using it works, but looking for other solutions if possible.

Comment: As of now, this does not seem to be possible. Any pressing reason why you dont want to create temp files?

Comment: using drag drop we can set multiple formats for same data. e. g.  if i drag an image file in adobe illustrator it will place the file (pdf format) and same image when dropped in sublime text editor (svg code) will place the code.

Comment: I'm just experimenting with things, if you've used http://www.svgs.us see two videos, I'm trying to do the same.  maybe need different solution but tried many concepts.

Comment: Seems neat, but as of now I see no way to implement it using the current Electron API. You should consider creating an issue on Github project https://github.com/electron/electron.

Comment: the application i mentioned is based on electron itself but not open source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128025/discussion-between-jens-habegger-and-vijayant-katyal).